# error "0: command not found" on a comment line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Help! I get an error A1.sh: line 205: 0: command not found after running my script.

What baffles me is that the line 205 is a comment! I have tried editing it but still get an error on the same line. All my line endings are LF.

Below is the block of code after editing, line 205 is now:

```
if `doesBookExist "$title" "$author"`
```

Full block of code:

```
if [[ bookExist -gt 0 ]]
then
    # get title from actual book (in case title input has bad case)
    actualTitle=`cut -d ':' -f 1 BookDB.txt | grep -i "^$title$"`
    sed -i "/^$title:$author.*$/Id" $FILENAME
    if `doesBookExist "$title" "$author"`
    then
        title=`echo "$title" | tr "@" ":"`
        echo
        echo "Book title '$actualTitle' could not be removed!"
    else
        title=`echo "$title" | tr "@" ":"`
        echo
        echo "Book title '$actualTitle' removed successfully!"
    fi
else
    echo
    echo 'Book does not exist!'
fi
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If takes a command as an argument, the 0 is read as a command after the actual command is executed by the backticks.

Comment: Very likely you are confused about the line number. If bash starts counting lines at 1 and your editor or whatever tool at 0, there's an off-by-one for the line number.

Comment: @Jens The problematic line is 4 lines away.

Answer (score 3):

In bash, `if` expects a command as second argument. What you gave it is the returncode of your command substitution, which is 0 - not a legal command.

So you need not do this:

```
if `doesBookExist "$title" "$author"`
```

but just this:

```
if doesBookExist "$title" "$author"
```

By the way: `$(somecommand someargs)` is the preferred way for command substitution - when you need it - as it can be arbitrarily nested.

Answer (score 0):

The backticks perform **command substitution**. It looks as if after command substitution you are trying to run

```
 if 0
 then
   ...
 fi
```

which explains the error message. But you want to compare the output to a string. This is most flexibly done with a case statement:

```
 case $(doesBookExist "$title" "$author") in
 (0)
   # if it is 0
   ;;
 (1)
   # if it is 1
   ;;
 esac
```